# How can I space out the links on my menu bar?

Tags: html

[image]

Thats a picture of of the menu bar. as you can see it is very close together. (click the link to see photo)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the html & css code of the menu bar and read this: [mcve]

Comment: I've embedded your image directly into your post, but I agree with Fabian, your question will receive a much better response a sample of your code. This is a fairly easy fix, but you need to provide the right context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either margins or padding in CSS.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

to space out your link you can use "PADING LEFT" here is a small link to give some explanation :)
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp
http://dabblet.com/gist/5b2553d1b366469d0b3979a0905a9c7e

Comment: Thank You for your help!